# MySQL Remove repeating clauses in subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct, union

I'm trying to simplify my query so that it only contains the session ID (SID) once.

The abstract structure of the Users table is:

```
+----+------+----------+
| ID | Name | Username |
+----+------+----------+
```

The Friends table has an abstract structure like:

```
+----+-----------------+----------+--------+---------+
| ID |     UserID      | FriendID | Hidden | Deleted |
|    | (Foreign key    |          |        |         |
|    | of ID in Users) |          |        |         |
+----+-----------------+----------+--------+---------+
```

The abstract structure of the Sessions table:

```
+----+-----------------+-----+
| ID |     UserID      | SID |
|    | (Foreign key    |     |
|    | of ID in Users) |     |
+----+-----------------+-----+
```

I have the following query, which has been adapted from the answer of a previous question of mine. As you can see, the session ID (SID) is repeated 4 times, is it possible to condense the query as a whole so that the SID is only required once?

```
SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN D.ID IS NULL
            THEN "Wants to be your friend"
        ELSE "Friends"
        END AS STATUS
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.ID
        ,A.NAME
        ,E.Hidden
    FROM Users A
    INNER JOIN Friends E ON A.ID = E.UserID
    WHERE A.ID IN (
            SELECT A.UserID
            FROM Friends A
            INNER JOIN Sessions S ON A.FriendID = S.UserID
            WHERE S.SID = "1234"
                AND Deleted = 'No'
            )
    ) C
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT B.ID
        ,B.NAME
        ,F.Hidden
    FROM Users B
    INNER JOIN Friends F ON B.ID = F.FriendID
    WHERE B.ID IN (
            SELECT A.FriendID
            FROM Friends A
            INNER JOIN Sessions S ON A.UserID = S.UserID
            WHERE S.SID = "1234"
                AND Deleted = 'No'
            )
    ) D ON C.ID = D.ID

UNION

    DISTINCT
SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN C.ID IS NULL
            THEN "Request Sent"
        ELSE "Friends"
        END AS STATUS
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.ID
        ,A.NAME
        ,E.Hidden
    FROM Users A
    INNER JOIN Friends E ON A.ID = E.UserID
    WHERE A.ID IN (
            SELECT A.UserID
            FROM Friends A
            INNER JOIN Sessions S ON A.FriendID = S.UserID
            WHERE S.SID = "1234"
                AND Deleted = 'No'
            )
    ) C
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT B.ID
        ,B.NAME
        ,F.Hidden
    FROM Users B
    INNER JOIN Friends F ON B.ID = F.FriendID
    WHERE B.ID IN (
            SELECT A.FriendID
            FROM Friends A
            INNER JOIN Sessions S ON A.UserID = S.UserID
            WHERE S.SID = "1234"
                AND Deleted = 'No'
            )
    ) D ON C.ID = D.ID
```

A basic way of explaining the system is that if two users are friends, then there is two records within the database. One from the first user to the second and another record from the second user to the first.

A friend request has been sent if there is a record from the current user to another, and a friend request has been received if there is a record from one user to the current one.

Here is a vann diagram of how it works:

[image: Venn Diagram]

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5587/1

Comment: it would be much more readable if you could indent your request.

Comment: Try using http://poorsql.com/

Comment: can you post a sqlfiddle with some data for us to play with? and also what is your desired output?

Comment: I will set one up and let you know when I have done it! I want an output with 3 columns: the name of the user, the ID of that user and their status (friends, request sent, request received)

Comment: @JohnRuddell I've added a sql fiddle link to the question

Comment: I managed to considerabely reduce the request size, but i don't think you can remove all union, you need at least ONE, so 2 WHERE

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond could you post the query you've made as an answer

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease I speak a little to fast, actually i just got the first part (return friends && Request Sent), but i'm still fighting with sql fiddle to figure out how to have a faster enought query for the Request Received

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease Just edited my post below, added an SQL fiddle, but i give up for the second part, i can't find out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54142/discussion-between-anthony-raymond-and-josh-luke-blease).

Answer (score 0):

Sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06e08/68/0

This return `Friends and Request Sent` :

```
SELECT 
  f.FriendID,
  u.Name,
  f.Hidden,
  CASE
    WHEN reqs.FriendID IS NULL
      THEN "Request Sent"
    WHEN reqs.FriendID = f.UserID
      THEN "Friends"
  END AS Status
FROM
  Friends AS f
  INNER JOIN
    Sessions AS s
    ON f.UserId = s.UserID
  INNER JOIN
    Users AS u
    ON u.ID = f.FriendID
  LEFT JOIN
    Friends AS reqs
    ON reqs.FriendID = f.UserID 
      AND reqs.UserID = f.FriendID
WHERE
  s.SID = "sid1"
```

If you want Also `Request Received`, append this :

```
UNION

SELECT
  f.UserID,
  u.Name,
  f.Hidden,
  "Request Received" AS Status
FROM
  Friends AS f
  INNER JOIN
    Sessions AS s
    ON f.FriendID = s.UserID
  INNER JOIN
    Users AS u
    ON u.ID = f.UserID
WHERE 
  f.UserID NOT IN 
    (
      SELECT 
        ff.FriendID 
      FROM 
        Friends AS ff 
        INNER JOIN
          Sessions AS ss
          ON ff.UserID = ss.UserID
      WHERE ss.SID = "sid1"
    )
  AND s.SID = "sid1"
```

Can't figure out how to optimise the last part. Since it's a SELF JOIN it's a damn mind twister.

I understand this is not what you expected but, i can't get ride of all the SID, but this request should be faster than the one you currently use